# MySQL - INSERT with subQuery IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm so confused, SQL is not my strong suit.

I have been looking at the following answers, but i can get my own query to work:

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1;
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO `table` (value1, value2) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` 
      WHERE value1='stuff for value1' AND value2='stuff for value2') 
LIMIT 1
```

I want to insert the result of a subquery into a new table (matches), this is my query:

```
INSERT INTO matches (fk_object_id, object_adress, fk_lookout_id, lookout_name)
    (SELECT o.id as oid, o.adress as oa, l.id as lid, l.first_name as lfn 
    FROM geo_lookout gl
    JOIN geo_object go ON go.`fk_geo_id` = gl.`fk_geo_id`
    JOIN object o ON o.id = go.`fk_object_id`
    JOIN attri_object ao ON ao.`fk_object_id` = go.`fk_object_id`
    JOIN attri_lookout al ON al.`fk_attri_id` = ao.`fk_attri_id`
    JOIN lookout l ON l.`id` = al.`fk_lookout_id`
    WHERE o.`have_size` <= l.`max_size`
    AND o.`have_size` >= l.`min_size`
    GROUP BY o.id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matches WHERE fk_object_id = oid AND fk_lookout_id = lid)
LIMIT 1
```

I always get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matches WHERE fk_object_id = oid
>   AND fk_lookout_' at line 12

The big SELECT query with all the JOINS is working fine by itself:

```
oid        oa          lid         lfn
45    aGoodStreet       32    Andrew Phillis
44    aGoodStreet       32    Andrew Phillis
```

Do you guys see more clearly then i do? Probably :)

Kind regards

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected result with table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have parentheses around your `select`?  Presumably, you intend:

```
INSERT INTO matches (fk_object_id, object_adress, fk_lookout_id, lookout_name)
    SELECT o.id as oid, o.adress as oa, l.id as lid, l.first_name as lfn 
    FROM geo_lookout gl
    JOIN geo_object go ON go.`fk_geo_id` = gl.`fk_geo_id`
    JOIN object o ON o.id = go.`fk_object_id`
    JOIN attri_object ao ON ao.`fk_object_id` = go.`fk_object_id`
    JOIN attri_lookout al ON al.`fk_attri_id` = ao.`fk_attri_id`
    JOIN lookout l ON l.`id` = al.`fk_lookout_id`
    WHERE o.`have_size` <= l.`max_size` AND
          o.`have_size` >= l.`min_size` AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matches m WHERE m.fk_object_id = o.oid AND m.fk_lookout_id = l.lid)
    GROUP BY o.id
    LIMIT 1;
```

Note that I had to guess in the subquery where the columns come from.  Qualify all column references.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the parantheses just went there because i tried to imitate the reference code i posted. It works the same without them unfortunately.

Comment: @SimonWikenståhl . . . You are saying that this version returns the same error?  I don't think so.  It is not missing an alias on any subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff the query now works!

Big thanks!

This is the working query:

```
INSERT INTO matches (fk_object_id, object_adress, fk_lookout_id, lookout_name)
    SELECT o.id as oid, o.adress as oa, l.id as lid, l.first_name as lfn 
    FROM geo_lookout gl
    JOIN geo_object go ON go.`fk_geo_id` = gl.`fk_geo_id`
    JOIN object o ON o.id = go.`fk_object_id`
    JOIN attri_object ao ON ao.`fk_object_id` = go.`fk_object_id`
    JOIN attri_lookout al ON al.`fk_attri_id` = ao.`fk_attri_id`
    JOIN lookout l ON l.`id` = al.`fk_lookout_id`
    WHERE o.`have_size` <= l.`max_size` AND
          o.`have_size` >= l.`min_size` AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matches m JOIN object ON object.id = m.`fk_object_id` JOIN lookout ON lookout.id = m.`fk_lookout_id` WHERE m.fk_object_id = object.id AND m.fk_lookout_id = lookout.id)
    GROUP BY o.id;
```